# Assembly code support in source insight

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, source-insight, directory-browsing

Has anybody tried browsing assembly language file (filename.s) in source insight?

I just added whole Linux kernel project into source insight but it does not support any of the assembly files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In The File field -> Load file -> Browse [give path]-> File Type [make it as all]
Then you will find your ".s" file open it ,
You can use  it like normal files

Comment: Yes your procedure is pretty much like temporary purpose.
I dont think you can find anything using project search as the files are just opened instead of adding to project !!

Answer (score 1):

When you create the project in Sourceinsight, it adds all the types of files (like *.c, *.h, *.cpp, etc) it knows. It also adds assembly files but only '.asm' and '.inc' files. To include all *.s files as assembly file in the project, You need to tell Sourceinsight to treat '.s' files as assembly files.

This can be by Document Options->Document Type -> select the x86 ASM Source File and then add on the in file filter box inside * s along with *.asm and *.inc. Once you are done with this, now you re-add all the files from root directory of the project (Project->add and remove files) and you will get the *.s files in Sourceinsight.

Answer (score 0):

in settings tab you should find it out.
There is an option to add support for all file types.

Answer (score 0):

Method to unconditionally include all Files present in the directory (Folder) :

1. CREATE A NEW DOCUMENT TYPE :
   Go to `Options ==> Document Options ==> Document Type`.  Press 'Add Type' button.  Create some new type called `MY_Unconditional`.
   Set 'File Filter' for this type as, `*, *.*`. (`*` wild card indicates all the files. `*.*` indicates all the files all type of extension.)
   Close the dialog box.
2. ADD ALL FILES TO PROJECT :
    Go to `Project ==> Add and Remove Project Files`
3. Choose your directory
4. Uncheck the box, 'Show only known document types'. Now, it will show all the files in the directory.
5. Now, press 'Add All' button. press 'Add Tree' button also if required.