# ARM assembly in source insight

Tags: linux, assembly, source-insight

What would be the best way to read ARM assembly using source insight? I currently am reading code for the linux kernel using SI and so far everything has worked great. However, when I try to read ARM assembly it chokes.

I tried following the Stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051897/assembly-code-support-in-source-insight) and that just created weird formatting. Is that because SI only recognizes x86 assembly and does not / cannot work with ARM assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need to add a custom language to read ARM assembler? https://www.sourceinsight.com/download/custom-languages/